# LULC Classification of Sentinel-2 Using XGBoost in R

Tags: r, sentinel-2, land-classification

I am trying to do Land cover classification using xgboost in R language.

These are the following steps:

```
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
Warning message:
R graphics engine version 14 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed. 
> shp <- shapefile("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Sat\\Training Samples_1.shp")
> ras <- stack("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Sat\\Final TIFF\\subset.tiff")
> ras
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 6735, 11679, 78658065, 7  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent     : 512504.8, 629294.8, 1276355, 1343705  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : subset.1, subset.2, subset.3, subset.4, subset.5, subset.6, subset.7 

> shp
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 4 
extent      : 515066.7, 704552.5, 1265814, 1399478  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 6
names       :   Classname, Classvalue, RED, GREEN, BLUE,  Count 
min values  : Barren Land,          1,   0,   112,  106, 275174 
max values  :       Water,          4, 162,    91,   75, 893831
> library(xgboost)
> vals <- extract(ras,shp)
> classes <- as.numeric(as.factor(shp@data$class)) - 1
> 
> train <- data.matrix(vals)
> 
> classes <- as.numeric(as.factor(shp@data$class)) - 1
> 
> xgb <- xgboost(data = train, 
+                label = classes, 
+                eta = 0.1,
+                max_depth = 6, 
+                nround=100, 
+                objective = "multi:softmax",
+                num_class = length(unique(classes)),
+                nthread = 3)
Error in xgb.DMatrix(data, label = label, missing = missing) : 
  REAL() can only be applied to a 'numeric', not a 'list'
```

I get the Error:
Error in xgb.DMatrix(data, label = label, missing = missing) :
REAL() can only be applied to a 'numeric', not a 'list'.

I found the tutorial for this [here](https://www.gis-blog.com/xgboost-for-landcover-classification-in-r/)

It seems my shapefile was not compatible/correct. I created one in qgis using the SCP plugin and was able to run the code.

Also in `shp@data$class` instead of class we have to type the attribute on which we want to classify for me it was MC_ID(Macro Class ID).

I changed the line: `vals <- extract(ras,shp)` to `extract(ras, shp, fun=mean)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not look like `shp@data$class` exists. In "shp" I see Classvalue and Classname but not class. Also, since your vector data are polygons `extract(ras,shp)` results in a list object (all pixel values intersecting each polygon), which is likely the source of your error. If you provide an additional argument, that aggregates the polygon values, you can mitigate this issue.

Using `extract(ras, shp, fun=mean)` will return the aggregated mean for each polygon and result in a data.frame where each column will be the mean for the sampled raster.

---

Spatial prediction of xgboost objects, using raster or terra class objects, returns an error because `xgb.DMatrix`, which is used internally by the predict method, does not like data.frames. The solution is as simple as coercing the object passed to the newdata argument to a matrix. This object is returned internally within the raster or terra predict function(s) as a "subset" block of data indexed to the raster stack. As such, you need to write a function that coerces the returned object to a matrix then pass it to the `predict` function. Here is an example that works for both raster and terra `predict`.

```
gbm.pred <- function(model, data) {
  predict(model, as.matrix(data))
}
mdl.est <- predict(raster_object, xgboost.mdl, fun=gbm.pred)
```

Comment: I created a raster file by calling following function  `writeRaster(res, "test_output11", format = "GTiff")`   but I get a tiff file which looks black. <br/>

Comment: @Sahil Not sure what that has to do with the original problem? Were you able to run a model then estimate it using the predict function? If you are having issues with this phase of your modeling you need to submit a new question to the forum as it is a new issue. I also cannot see your code for the prediction so, have no idea what could be going wrong.